# Load External JSON into HTML

Tags: html, json, load

Im super new to HTML so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I currently have data is an external JSON, and call to load within the HTML. Instead of loading it, I just want to copy it into the HTML and save it as part of it. How would I do this without changing the data structure?

Example data JSON:

```
[
{ 
    "User" : "COMP",
    "Runtime" : 931.216111111
},
{ 
    "User" : "AUTO",
    "Runtime" : 600.404444444
}
]
```

Where I load it:

```
// load data
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.User = d.User;
        d.Runtime = +d.Runtime;
    });

  // scale the range of the data
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.User; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Runtime; })]);
```

I've looked at answers but my question is how do I copy it into the HTML and still be able to call d.Runtime and d.User parameters the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your HTML page, you'll need to add a script tag to hold the JavaScript.  It might be a good idea to put this in the body so it will be executed when the page is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Next, you'll need to define a constant for the data inside the script tag.  The contents of the .json file can be copied and pasted after the equal sign:

```
const data = [
  { 
    "User" : "COMP",
    "Runtime" : 931.216111111 
  },
  { 
    "User" : "AUTO",
    "Runtime" : 600.404444444
  }
]
```

Now you can append the code you had inside your d3.json callback:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.User = d.User;
    d.Runtime = +d.Runtime;
});

// scale the range of the data
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.User; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Runtime; })]);
```